# Word to Symbol converter

Tags: java, string

I want to make a system that when written a letter *(example:**a**)* it converts it to a symbols (example:**ԅ**).

How do I really do it? I know it seems simple, but I am **very, very new** into programming, all I can do is a simple calendar or a calculator.

I've tried to do it alone, but got nowhere. I type a whole word but it just prints the first letter instead of the word, that contains 4+. For example I type *"**aura**"* but it prints only *"**ԅ**"*

**THANKS A LOT TO ALL OF YOU!!! I FINALLY MADE IT!!!!**

Comment: Why did it fail?  Include your source code and some sample input so that we can see what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `HashMap<Character, Character>` in this case!

If you don't know what that is, it's basically a "dictionary". You can just make the `HashMap` like this in your case:

```
a -> ԅ
b -> !
c -> @
d -> #
```

**Note: The above is not real code, just a visual representation! And I don't know what your symbols mean and how to type them, so I used normal symbols**

See? It's really a dictionary. When you look for "a", you get "ԅ", when you look for "b", you get "!", etc. Do you get it now?

Okay, now let's see the code

```
HashMap<Character, Character> characterMap = new HashMap<> (); //Create a new HashMap
characterMap.put ('a', 'ԅ'); // Put an entry in the "dictionary"
characterMap.put ('b', '!');
//and so on... I am lazy
```

Now suppose you are able to get the user input and stored it in a string called `input`. Just like Anthony's code, you do this:

```
for (Map.Entry<Character, Character> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    input = input.replace(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

This is basically saying that,

```
Go to find every entry in the dictionary. 
For each entry,
    Store it in the "entry" variable
    Replace all the occurrences of entry's key by entry's value
```

Comment: You might have copy paster a block of code of my first answer .... i fixed 3 methods call that wasn't named properly....

Comment: Oops! I did. I edited it to mention you. @AnthonyRaymond

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you!!!

Answer (score 3):

Use `string = string.replace("a", "ԅ");`
where string is the given word (in your case, *aura*).

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a for loop that reads the string supplied one letter at a time then makes a new string that "translates" every individual letter.

Here's some quick code:

```
Scanner i = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter string:");
String start = i.next();
int len = start.length;
String end = "";

for (int a = 0, a<len, a++) {
    if (start.Charat(a) == "a") {
        end = end.append(ԅ)
    } etc...
}
```

I just made this off the top of my head, I'll try to make a working version if you give me more substitutions :)

Comment: This is why String.replace was created

Comment: I'm pretty new to java lol. I'm just doing my best to offer help

Answer (score 2):

Hi @EpicJavaNoob and welcome on StackOverflow.

You could solve your problem by using a `Map` and `replace()` function on Strings.

You have to create this class in your program.

```
public class MyReplacer {
    private static final Map<Character, Character> map = new HashMap<Character, Character>();
    static { // the static block is used to instantiate the Map once for all
        map.put('a' , '\u2026');
        map.put('b', '+');
    }

    public static String encode(String stringToEncode) {
        // for each entry in the hashmap, we replace the character by his corresponding key
        for (Map.Entry<Character, Character> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            stringToEncode = stringToEncode.replace(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        return stringToEncode;
    }
}
```

Then in your code you can use the previous class this way :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "aura";
    String encodedStr = MyReplacer.encode(str);
}
```

A Map is use to associate a key to a value.

I do agree that this is not the simple solution you can find, but this is how you'l learn coding, looking at code wrote by other and try to understand how it works, and why it has ben wrote this way.

Comment: Don't use `replaceAll` (this uses regex, which is not used in this case). Use `replace`

Comment: @MCMastery fixed, thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to code a Translator class with a translation table:

**Edit**: I've chosen the Map alternative instead of the `char[]` one (my first thought), after agreeing with AnthonyRaymond's suggest.

```
public class Translator
{
    private Map<Character,Character> table=createTable();

    public String translate(String input)
    {...}
}
```

To construct the table, you must set just the explicit mappings (in order to reduce the table to the minimum size):

```
private Map<Character,Character> createTable()
{
    Map<Character,Character> table=new HashMap<Character,Character>();

    // Set the explicit mappings:
    table.put('a', 'ԅ');
    table.put('b', ...);

    return table;
}
```

The translation rutine must first index the table, and if the character is not found, select the input character (in order to leave untranslated the blanks, newlines and rest of non-translatable characters):

```
public String translate(String input)
{
    StringBuilder stb=new StringBuilder(input.length());
    for (int i=0;i<input.length();i++)
    {
        char inputChar=input.charAt(i);
        Character outputChar=table.get(inputChar);
        if (outputChar==null)
        {
            outputChar=inputChar;
        }
        stb.append(outputChar);
    }
    return stb.toString();
}
```

Comment: I bet `table['a']='ԅ';` will work, but showing this to a beginer is imo not the best idea. It's a practice that comes right from hell ^^

Comment: @AnthonyRaymond Maybe you are right, but this is the way I usually code char mappings: it's efficient and easy... Well, I thought so. What would you suggest? A `Map` instead of a `char[]`?

Comment: Yeah, i'd rather take advantage of Objects vs primitive types. Plus 65536 index looks like a big array ^^

Comment: Yes, you are right: It is more didactic with a Map, and smaller in size. (BTW: 65K is the total addressing space for a `char` index). And thanks.